# Random hangs every 15-30 minutes

Tags: linux

These are some last errors show on `journalctl -r` before I restart the computer:

```
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: ---[ end trace 9fa0f307295d110f ]---
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel:  RSP <ffff8803f39abe98>
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: RIP  [<ffffffff814828c3>] sockfd_lookup_light+0x53/0x70
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: Code: fc 74 18 48 81 7f 28 e0 be 66 81 48 89 c1 74 12 c7 03 a8 ff ff ff 83 e1 01 75 1c 5b 31 c0 41 5c 5d c3 48 8b 87 d0 00 00 00 48 85 <c0> 74 e8 5b 41 89 14 24 41 5c 5d c3 e8
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel:  [<ffffffff815a64ae>] ? entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x12/0x6d
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel:  [<ffffffff814844e2>] ? SyS_sendmsg+0x12/0x20
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel:  [<ffffffff811e4b5c>] ? SyS_read+0xac/0xc0
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel:  [<ffffffff811e3e2f>] ? vfs_read+0x10f/0x130
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel:  [<ffffffff81484474>] ? __sys_sendmsg+0x34/0x90
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: Call Trace:
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel:  ffff8803f3b59701 ffff8803f3b59700 00007f63c58e6b67 0000000000000001
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel:  fffffff7f457fbe8 ffff8803f3b59710 ffff8803f39abf00 ffffffff811e3e2f
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel:  0000000000000044 00007f63c58e5778 ffff8803f39abf38 ffffffff81484474
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: Stack:
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: CR2: 00007f63c8565213 CR3: 00000003f3a2e000 CR4: 00000000001406e0
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: FS:  00007f63c58e7700(0000) GS:ffff88041fb80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: R13: 0000000000000040 R14: 00007f639d868948 R15: 00007f63c58e67b0
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: R10: 00007f639f72be00 R11: 0000000000000293 R12: ffff8803f39abeb8
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: RBP: ffff8803d747d680 R08: ffff8803f396ca38 R09: 00007f639b991000
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: RDX: 0000000000000001 RSI: ffff8803d0bac220 RDI: ffff8803f396ca00
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: RAX: ffff8803f39abea8 RBX: ffff8803f39abebc RCX: ffff8803f396ca01
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: RSP: 0018:ffff8803f39abe98  EFLAGS: 00010246
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff814828c3>]  [<ffffffff814828c3>] sockfd_lookup_light+0x53/0x70
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: task: ffff8803eb3d6040 ti: ffff8803f39a8000 task.ti: ffff8803f39a8000
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: Hardware name: ASUS All Series/H81M-E, BIOS 2107 11/21/2014
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: CPU: 3 PID: 1687 Comm: Gecko_IOThread Tainted: G      D         4.4.24-1-MANJARO #1
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel:  serio_raw atkbd libps2 xhci_pci ahci libahci libata ehci_pci xhci_hcd ehci_hcd scsi_mod usbcore usb_common i8042 serio
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: Modules linked in: fuse uas usb_storage joydev mousedev input_leds intel_rapl iosf_mbi x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclm
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: SMP 
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: PREEMPT 
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: ---[ end trace 9fa0f307295d110e ]---
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: general protection fault: 0000 [#8] 
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel:  RSP <ffff8803eb317e98>
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: RIP  [<ffffffff814828c3>] sockfd_lookup_light+0x53/0x70
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: Code: fc 74 18 48 81 7f 28 e0 be 66 81 48 89 c1 74 12 c7 03 a8 ff ff ff 83 e1 01 75 1c 5b 31 c0 41 5c 5d c3 48 8b 87 d0 00 00 00 48 85 <c0> 74 e8 5b 41 89 14 24 41 5c 5d c3 e8
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel:  [<ffffffff815a64ae>] ? entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x12/0x6d
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel:  [<ffffffff81484772>] ? SyS_recvmsg+0x12/0x20
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel:  [<ffffffff811e8ed6>] ? SyS_newlstat+0x36/0x70
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel:  [<ffffffff81484704>] ? __sys_recvmsg+0x34/0x90
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: Call Trace:
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel:  000000009292c96f 000000000bebc200 0000000000000003 0000000001f4e1d0
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel:  fffffff7020ca840 ffff8803eb317f48 ffffffff811e8ed6 ffff8803eb317f20
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel:  0000000000000007 00007ffcf4890330 ffff8803eb317f38 ffffffff81484704
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: Stack:
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: CR2: 00007f52b2d3cbaf CR3: 00000003eb298000 CR4: 00000000001406e0
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: FS:  00007f82a44db940(0000) GS:ffff88041fa80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 0000000001fa3640 R15: 00007f82a361b7c0
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000293 R12: ffff8803eb317eb8
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: RBP: ffff8803f5eb6300 R08: ffff8803eb27e338 R09: 00007f82a1ee78e0
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: RDX: 0000000000000001 RSI: ffff8803eb0b8bd8 RDI: ffff8803eb27e300
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: RAX: ffff8803eb317ea8 RBX: ffff8803eb317ebc RCX: ffff8803eb27e301
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: RSP: 0018:ffff8803eb317e98  EFLAGS: 00010246
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff814828c3>]  [<ffffffff814828c3>] sockfd_lookup_light+0x53/0x70
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: task: ffff88040c248dc0 ti: ffff8803eb314000 task.ti: ffff8803eb314000
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: Hardware name: ASUS All Series/H81M-E, BIOS 2107 11/21/2014
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: CPU: 1 PID: 1642 Comm: pamac-tray Tainted: G      D         4.4.24-1-MANJARO #1
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel:  serio_raw atkbd libps2 xhci_pci ahci libahci libata ehci_pci xhci_hcd ehci_hcd scsi_mod usbcore usb_common i8042 serio
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: Modules linked in: fuse uas usb_storage joydev mousedev input_leds intel_rapl iosf_mbi x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclm
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: SMP 
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: PREEMPT 
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: ---[ end trace 9fa0f307295d110d ]---
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: general protection fault: 0000 [#7] 
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel:  RSP <ffff8803f384fe80>
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: RIP  [<ffffffff814828c3>] sockfd_lookup_light+0x53/0x70
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: Code: fc 74 18 48 81 7f 28 e0 be 66 81 48 89 c1 74 12 c7 03 a8 ff ff ff 83 e1 01 75 1c 5b 31 c0 41 5c 5d c3 48 8b 87 d0 00 00 00 48 85 <c0> 74 e8 5b 41 89 14 24 41 5c 5d c3 e8
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel:  [<ffffffff815a64ae>] ? entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x12/0x6d
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel:  [<ffffffff8148361f>] ? SyS_socket+0x9f/0xf0
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel:  [<ffffffff812009f5>] ? fd_install+0x25/0x30
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel:  [<ffffffff81480d15>] ? sock_alloc_file+0xa5/0x130
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel:  [<ffffffff814838bd>] ? SyS_bind+0x3d/0xe0
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: Call Trace:
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel:  ffffffff81480d15 0000000069c37d82 000000000000001b 0000000000000000
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel:  fffffffffffffff7 0000000000000000 ffff8800a5235e00 ffff8803f384ff08
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel:  00007ff79f0a5db0 000000000000000c ffff8803f384ff48 ffffffff814838bd
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: Stack:
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: CR2: 00007f52b2d3fae8 CR3: 00000003f6b2f000 CR4: 00000000001406f0
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: FS:  00007ff79f0a7700(0000) GS:ffff88041fa00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: R13: 00007ff79f0a5d00 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 00007ff79f0a5f90
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: R10: 000000000336f4a0 R11: 0000000000000206 R12: ffff8803f384fea4
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: RBP: ffff8800a5235e00 R08: ffff880359c20e38 R09: 0000000002bc3000
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: RDX: 0000000000000001 RSI: ffff880037812d78 RDI: ffff880359c20e00
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: RAX: ffff8803f384fe90 RBX: ffff8803f384fea0 RCX: ffff880359c20e01
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: RSP: 0018:ffff8803f384fe80  EFLAGS: 00010246
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff814828c3>]  [<ffffffff814828c3>] sockfd_lookup_light+0x53/0x70
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: task: ffff8803efe88dc0 ti: ffff8803f384c000 task.ti: ffff8803f384c000
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: Hardware name: ASUS All Series/H81M-E, BIOS 2107 11/21/2014
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: CPU: 0 PID: 1664 Comm: Qt bearer threa Tainted: G      D         4.4.24-1-MANJARO #1
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel:  serio_raw atkbd libps2 xhci_pci ahci libahci libata ehci_pci xhci_hcd ehci_hcd scsi_mod usbcore usb_common i8042 serio
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: Modules linked in: fuse uas usb_storage joydev mousedev input_leds intel_rapl iosf_mbi x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclm
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: SMP 
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: PREEMPT 
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: ---[ end trace 9fa0f307295d110c ]---
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: ---[ end trace 9fa0f307295d110b ]---
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: general protection fault: 0000 [#6] 
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel:  RSP <ffff8803f6bc7e98>
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: RIP  [<ffffffff814828c3>] sockfd_lookup_light+0x53/0x70
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: Code: fc 74 18 48 81 7f 28 e0 be 66 81 48 89 c1 74 12 c7 03 a8 ff ff ff 83 e1 01 75 1c 5b 31 c0 41 5c 5d c3 48 8b 87 d0 00 00 00 48 95 <c0> 74 e8 5b 41 89 14 24 41 5c 5d c3 e8
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel:  [<ffffffff815a64ae>] ? entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x12/0x6d
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel:  [<ffffffff81484772>] ? SyS_recvmsg+0x12/0x20
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel:  [<ffffffff811e9061>] ? SyS_readlinkat+0x91/0x130
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel:  [<ffffffff811ed56e>] ? path_put+0x1e/0x30
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel:  [<ffffffff81484704>] ? __sys_recvmsg+0x34/0x90
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: Call Trace:
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel:  ffff8803f6bc7f38 ffffffff811e9061 0000100000000021 00000000f6bc7f28
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel:  fffffff781203014 ffff8803f6bc7ed8 ffffffff811ed56e 0000000000004000
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel:  0000000000000006 00007ffc984a6a30 ffff8803f6bc7f38 ffffffff81484704
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: Stack:
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: CR2: 00007f5b4294a010 CR3: 00000003f6b5a000 CR4: 00000000001406e0
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: FS:  00007f6e733397c0(0000) GS:ffff88041fb00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 0000000001a6a960 R15: 00007f6e5d0517c0
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: R10: 0000000000000025 R11: 0000000000000293 R12: ffff8803f6bc7eb8
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: RBP: ffff8803f5f67c00 R08: ffff8803f3a5a338 R09: 0000000000000000
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: RDX: 0000000000000001 RSI: ffff880037812490 RDI: ffff8803f3a5a300
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: RAX: ffff8803f6bc7ea8 RBX: ffff8803f6bc7ebc RCX: ffff8803f3a5a301
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: RSP: 0018:ffff8803f6bc7e98  EFLAGS: 00010246
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff814828c3>]  [<ffffffff814828c3>] sockfd_lookup_light+0x53/0x70
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: task: ffff880406261b80 ti: ffff8803f6bc4000 task.ti: ffff8803f6bc4000
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: Hardware name: ASUS All Series/H81M-E, BIOS 2107 11/21/2014
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: CPU: 2 PID: 1521 Comm: yakuake Tainted: G      D         4.4.24-1-MANJARO #1
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel:  serio_raw atkbd libps2 xhci_pci ahci libahci libata ehci_pci xhci_hcd ehci_hcd scsi_mod usbcore usb_common i8042 serio
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: Modules linked in: fuse uas usb_storage joydev mousedev input_leds intel_rapl iosf_mbi x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclm
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: SMP 
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: PREEMPT 
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: ---[ end trace 9fa0f307295d110a ]---
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: ---[ end trace 9fa0f307295d1109 ]---
Oct 21 10:08:11 test-pc kernel: general protection fault: 0000 [#5] 
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel:  RSP <ffff88040bc0fe98>
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: RIP  [<ffffffff814828c3>] sockfd_lookup_light+0x53/0x70
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: Code: fc 74 18 48 81 7f 28 e0 be 66 81 48 89 c1 74 12 c7 03 a8 ff ff ff 83 e1 01 75 1c 5b 31 c0 41 5c 5d c3 48 8b 87 d0 00 00 00 48 95 <c0> 74 e8 5b 41 89 14 24 41 5c 5d c3 e8
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel:  [<ffffffff815a64ae>] ? entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x12/0x6d
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel:  [<ffffffff81484772>] ? SyS_recvmsg+0x12/0x20
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel:  [<ffffffff810e941b>] ? ktime_get_ts64+0x4b/0x100
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel:  [<ffffffff81484704>] ? __sys_recvmsg+0x34/0x90
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: Call Trace:
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel:  0000000053ced961 000000000ed77040 0000000000000002 00007f4e250936c0
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel:  fffffff700000001 ffff88040bc0fee8 ffffffff810e941b ffff88040bc0ff20
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel:  0000000000000099 00007f4df5cba6c0 ffff88040bc0ff38 ffffffff81484704
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: Stack:
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: CR2: 00007f63c8565213 CR3: 0000000368874000 CR4: 00000000001406e0
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: FS:  00007f4df5cbb700(0000) GS:ffff88041fb80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 00007f4e8c8b27e0 R15: 00007f4e8c913800
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: R10: 00007f4e3f30d404 R11: 0000000000000293 R12: ffff88040bc0feb8
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: RBP: ffff8803d747e080 R08: ffff8803efc86b38 R09: 0000000000000005
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: RDX: 0000000000000001 RSI: ffff8804061b44c8 RDI: ffff8803efc86b00
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: RAX: ffff88040bc0fea8 RBX: ffff88040bc0febc RCX: ffff8803efc86b01
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: RSP: 0018:ffff88040bc0fe98  EFLAGS: 00010246
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff814828c3>]  [<ffffffff814828c3>] sockfd_lookup_light+0x53/0x70
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: task: ffff8800bfc1c4c0 ti: ffff88040bc0c000 task.ti: ffff88040bc0c000
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: Hardware name: ASUS All Series/H81M-E, BIOS 2107 11/21/2014
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: CPU: 3 PID: 2299 Comm: java Tainted: G      D         4.4.24-1-MANJARO #1
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel:  serio_raw atkbd libps2 xhci_pci ahci libahci libata ehci_pci xhci_hcd ehci_hcd scsi_mod usbcore usb_common i8042 serio
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: Modules linked in: fuse uas usb_storage joydev mousedev input_leds intel_rapl iosf_mbi x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclm
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: general protection fault: 0000 [#4] PREEMPT SMP 
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel:  RSP <ffff8803f390fe98>
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: RIP  [<ffffffff814828c3>] sockfd_lookup_light+0x53/0x70
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: Code: fc 74 18 48 81 7f 28 e0 be 66 81 48 89 c1 74 12 c7 03 a8 ff ff ff 83 e1 01 75 1c 5b 31 c0 41 5c 5d c3 48 8b 87 d0 00 00 00 48 95 <c0> 74 e8 5b 41 89 14 24 41 5c 5d c3 e8
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel:  [<ffffffff815a64ae>] ? entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x12/0x6d
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel:  [<ffffffff81484772>] ? SyS_recvmsg+0x12/0x20
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel:  [<ffffffff810e941b>] ? ktime_get_ts64+0x4b/0x100
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel:  [<ffffffff81484704>] ? __sys_recvmsg+0x34/0x90
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: Call Trace:
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel:  00000000083b6d02 000000000ef5f4c0 0000000000000005 00007f63b56b2280
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel:  fffffff700000001 ffff8803f390fee8 ffffffff810e941b ffff8803f390ff20
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel:  0000000000000004 00007ffe431102f0 ffff8803f390ff38 ffffffff81484704
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: Stack:
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: CR2: 00007f52b2d3cbaf CR3: 00000003f3a2e000 CR4: 00000000001406e0
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: FS:  00007f63dd84a740(0000) GS:ffff88041fa80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 00007f63c841b000 R15: 00007f63db8a4740
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: R10: 00007f63bf23acc0 R11: 0000000000000293 R12: ffff8803f390feb8
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: RBP: ffff8803f5f63200 R08: ffff8803f393cf38 R09: 0000000000000005
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: RDX: 0000000000000001 RSI: ffff8803d0bac020 RDI: ffff8803f393cf00
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: RAX: ffff8803f390fea8 RBX: ffff8803f390febc RCX: ffff8803f393cf01
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: RSP: 0018:ffff8803f390fe98  EFLAGS: 00010246
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff814828c3>]  [<ffffffff814828c3>] sockfd_lookup_light+0x53/0x70
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: task: ffff8800cde4b700 ti: ffff8803f390c000 task.ti: ffff8803f390c000
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: Hardware name: ASUS All Series/H81M-E, BIOS 2107 11/21/2014
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: CPU: 1 PID: 1682 Comm: firefox Tainted: G      D         4.4.24-1-MANJARO #1
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel:  serio_raw atkbd libps2 xhci_pci ahci libahci libata ehci_pci xhci_hcd ehci_hcd scsi_mod usbcore usb_common i8042 serio
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: Modules linked in: fuse uas usb_storage joydev mousedev input_leds intel_rapl iosf_mbi x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclm
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: general protection fault: 0000 [#3] PREEMPT SMP 
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel:  RSP <ffff88040c49be98>
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: RIP  [<ffffffff814828c3>] sockfd_lookup_light+0x53/0x70
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: Code: fc 74 18 48 81 7f 28 e0 be 66 81 48 89 c1 74 12 c7 03 a8 ff ff ff 83 e1 01 75 1c 5b 31 c0 41 5c 5d c3 48 8b 87 d0 00 00 00 48 95 <c0> 74 e8 5b 41 89 14 24 41 5c 5d c3 e8
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel:  [<ffffffff815a64ae>] ? entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x12/0x6d
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel:  [<ffffffff81484772>] ? SyS_recvmsg+0x12/0x20
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel:  [<ffffffff81484704>] ? __sys_recvmsg+0x34/0x90
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: Call Trace:
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel:  000000001da85469 0000000000001000 0000000000000004 0000000000f846e0
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel:  fffffff700000001 0000000000000000 ffff880300000000 ffff880300000000
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel:  0000000000000003 00007ffd87c44a20 ffff88040c49bf38 ffffffff81484704
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: Stack:
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: CR2: 00007f63c8565213 CR3: 000000040cbde000 CR4: 00000000001406e0
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: FS:  00007f799eb26140(0000) GS:ffff88041fb80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 0000000000e8ff80 R15: 00007f799d906510
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: R10: 0000000000f71820 R11: 0000000000000293 R12: ffff88040c49beb8
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: RBP: ffff8800d3c83480 R08: ffff8803f681f238 R09: 0000000000000004
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: RDX: 0000000000000001 RSI: ffff8800378108f8 RDI: ffff8803f681f200
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: RAX: ffff88040c49bea8 RBX: ffff88040c49bebc RCX: ffff8803f681f201
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: RSP: 0018:ffff88040c49be98  EFLAGS: 00010246
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff814828c3>]  [<ffffffff814828c3>] sockfd_lookup_light+0x53/0x70
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: task: ffff88040b4fe040 ti: ffff88040c498000 task.ti: ffff88040c498000
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: Hardware name: ASUS All Series/H81M-E, BIOS 2107 11/21/2014
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: CPU: 3 PID: 1426 Comm: xfwm4 Tainted: G      D         4.4.24-1-MANJARO #1
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel:  serio_raw atkbd libps2 xhci_pci ahci libahci libata ehci_pci xhci_hcd ehci_hcd scsi_mod usbcore usb_common i8042 serio
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: Modules linked in: fuse uas usb_storage joydev mousedev input_leds intel_rapl iosf_mbi x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclm
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: SMP 
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: PREEMPT 
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: ---[ end trace 9fa0f307295d1108 ]---
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: general protection fault: 0000 [#2] 
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel:  RSP <ffff88040c523e98>
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: RIP  [<ffffffff814828c3>] sockfd_lookup_light+0x53/0x70
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: Code: fc 74 18 48 81 7f 28 e0 be 66 81 48 89 c1 74 12 c7 03 a8 ff ff ff 83 e1 01 75 1c 5b 31 c0 41 5c 5d c3 48 8b 87 d0 00 00 00 48 95 <c0> 74 e8 5b 41 89 14 24 41 5c 5d c3 e8
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel:  [<ffffffff815a64ae>] ? entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x12/0x6d
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel:  [<ffffffff81484772>] ? SyS_recvmsg+0x12/0x20
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel:  [<ffffffff811e5066>] ? SyS_writev+0xd6/0xf0
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel:  [<ffffffff811e4299>] ? vfs_writev+0x39/0x50
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel:  [<ffffffff81484704>] ? __sys_recvmsg+0x34/0x90
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: Call Trace:
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel:  00007ffe89eb7de0 0000000000000001 00000000013b1280 ffff88040c523f00
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel:  fffffff7e8071c96 0000000000000001 ffff8803f3a5fd01 ffff8803f3a5fd00
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel:  0000000000000031 00007ffe89eb7de0 ffff88040c523f38 ffffffff81484704
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: Stack:
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: CR2: 00007f52b2d3fae8 CR3: 000000040bca3000 CR4: 00000000001406f0
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: FS:  00007f4b7a3e1940(0000) GS:ffff88041fa00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 00000000013ecc90 R15: 0000000000000000
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: R10: 0000000000000008 R11: 0000000000003293 R12: ffff88040c523eb8
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: RBP: ffff8803f5eb3200 R08: ffff8803f3a5fd38 R09: 0000000000000000
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: RDX: 0000000000000001 RSI: ffff8800371f4188 RDI: ffff8803f3a5fd00
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: RAX: ffff88040c523ea8 RBX: ffff88040c523ebc RCX: ffff8803f3a5fd01
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: RSP: 0018:ffff88040c523e98  EFLAGS: 00010246
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff814828c3>]  [<ffffffff814828c3>] sockfd_lookup_light+0x53/0x70
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: task: ffff880406f4c4c0 ti: ffff88040c520000 task.ti: ffff88040c520000
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: Hardware name: ASUS All Series/H81M-E, BIOS 2107 11/21/2014
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: CPU: 0 PID: 588 Comm: Xorg Not tainted 4.4.24-1-MANJARO #1
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel:  serio_raw atkbd libps2 xhci_pci ahci libahci libata ehci_pci xhci_hcd ehci_hcd scsi_mod usbcore usb_common i8042 serio
Oct 21 10:08:09 test-pc kernel: Modules linked in: fuse uas usb_storage joydev mousedev input_leds intel_rapl iosf_mbi x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclm
Oct 21 10:08:03 test-pc kernel: general protection fault: 0000 [#1] PREEMPT SMP 
*snip*
```

continues at http://pastebin.com/LYv0takv

Sometimes some program closed by itself:

```
Oct 21 10:44:30 test-pc systemd-coredump[5738]: Process 1284 (java) of user 1000 dumped core.

                                                    Stack trace of thread 1296:
                                                    #0  0x00007f91a097904f n/a (n/a)
Oct 21 10:44:11 test-pc systemd[1]: Started Process Core Dump (PID 5737/UID 0).
Oct 21 10:44:11 test-pc systemd[1]: Created slice system-systemd\x2dcoredump.slice.
Oct 21 10:42:33 test-pc systemd[1]: Started Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Oct 21 10:42:33 test-pc systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
Oct 21 10:32:16 test-pc kernel: EXT4-fs (sda2): last error at time 1471231923: ext4_readdir:164: inode 24906427
Oct 21 10:32:16 test-pc kernel: EXT4-fs (sda2): initial error at time 1471231923: ext4_readdir:164: inode 24906427
Oct 21 10:32:16 test-pc kernel: EXT4-fs (sda2): error count since last fsck: 2
```

Linux: Linux test-pc 3.18.42-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Sep 19 20:20:15 UTC 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux

`memtest86+` results are ok (only tested until test 8).

What are the possible cause of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check your drive /dev/sda with smartmontools.

> kernel: EXT4-fs (sda2): last error at time 1471231923:
>   ext4_readdir:164: inode 24906427